# Why SkiaSharp 'OnCanvasView_PaintSurface' doesn't re-draw automatically in Xamarin.Form App

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a SkiaCanvasView and a Label in a StackLayout in Xamarin.Form app, trying to update the bitmap on screen frequently, but it draws only once. The XAML file and CS code are as follows,

```
<StackLayout 
    x:Name="stackMonitors"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label x:Name="numCounter"
           Text="counter"
           VerticalOptions="Start"/>
    <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                       PaintSurface="OnCanvasView_PaintSurface"
                       VerticalOptions ="FillAndExpand"
                       Margin="10,10,0,10"/>

</StackLayout>


SKBitmap skiBMP = new SKBitmap();
SKSurface skiSurface;
SKCanvas skiCanvas;
SKPaint skiPaint = new SKPaint();
SKRect skiRect = new SKRect();
int temp = 0;
private void OnCanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    numCounter.Text = (++temp).ToString();    //if the PaintSurface is called more than once automatically, the numCounter should not be "1" all the time
    skiSurface = e.Surface;
    skiCanvas = skiSurface.Canvas;
    skiRect.Top = 0;
    skiRect.Left = 0;
    skiRect.Right = e.Info.Width;
    skiRect.Bottom = e.Info.Width * 0.5625f;

    skiBMP = SKBitmap.Decode(myOperator.PCImageMemoryStream);  //Bitmap stream updates 30 times per second
    skiCanvas.DrawBitmap(skiBMP, skiRect, skiPaint);
}
```

**Expected Result**

The value of myOperator.PCImageMemoryStream constantly updates, I expected that OnCanvasView_PaintSurface event would be automatically triggered 60 times every second, so the CanvasView can draw myOperator.PCImageMemoryStream on the MainPage very frequently.

**Actual Result**

However, it draws only once, the label "numCounter" shows "1" all the time after running the app.

**Summary**

I'm wondering how the OnCanvasView_PaintSurface can be called as device screen refreshes each time. Microsoft Skia Webinar said Skia CanvasView paints itself 60 times every second...

(and what is worse is that after taking reference of SkiaSharp in the project, the XAML file cannot be previewed properly ...)

Thanks very much.

Comment: you need to call InvalidateSurface() in order to tell the canvas that it needs to be redrawn

Comment: hmm, heard about this InvalidateSurface method, I finally figured it out today that this method belonged to CanvasView, rather than Canvas. IoI    Thank you so much!